# Trying to connect from Databricks to on-premise SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-databricks

I am using databricks and I want to load data from an on-premises SQL Server that I install via libraries (e.g. com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2_12:1.3.0) or the one standard driver supplied by Databricks. Both lead to the same result.

When running

```
remote_table = spark.read \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("database", database) \
    .option("encrypt", "true") \
    .option("trustServerCertificate", "true") \
    .option("dbtable", table) \
    .option("integratedSecurity", "true") \
    .load()
```

I get the following error message.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.

Removing integrated security, the logs on the SQL Server return that it tries to use SQL Server authentication (for which it is not configured)

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC driver supports Windows Integrated auth with either Kerberos or NTLM.  Kerberos requires [setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) on the OS that you may not be able to perform on Databricks cluster nodes.

NTLM is normally not avaialable from Linux clients, but the JDBC driver has implemented it directly, and supports NTLM with provided credentials.

See [Using NTLM Authentication to connect to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) by setting the [authenticationScheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver16) connection string property to "NTLM".